# Apache Solr what does cat:iphone^2 name:iphone^2 mean?

Tags: solr, lucene

I am reading "apache solr search patterns" book and there are queries:

```
q=text:iphone cat:iphone^2 name:iphone^2
brand:iphone^2&facet=true&facet.mincount=1&facet.field=clothes_
gender&facet.field=clothes_type&facet.field=clothes_size&facet.
field=clothes_color&facet.field=brand&facet.field=mobile_os&facet.
field=mobile_screen_size&facet.field=laptop_processor&facet.
field=laptop_memory&facet.field=laptop_hard_disk&defType=edismax
```

and

```
q=pink sweater&qf=text cat^2 name^2 brand^2 clothes_type^2 clothes_
color^2 clothes_occassion^2&pf=text cat^3 name^3 brand^3 clothes_
type^3 clothes_color^3 clothes_occassion^3&fl=*,score&defType=edi
smax&facet=true&facet.mincount=1&facet.field=clothes_gender&facet.
field=clothes_type&facet.field=clothes_size&facet.field=clothes_
color&facet.field=brand&facet.field=mobile_os&facet.field=mobile_
screen_size&facet.field=laptop_processor&facet.field=laptop_
memory&facet.field=laptop_hard_disk
```

what does those ^2 and ^3 mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means to give a 2x or 3x boost to those terms if found in those fields. The syntax is `field:term^<weight>`. See [Boosting a term with ^](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_7/the-standard-query-parser.html#boosting-a-term-with) in the reference guide.

> Lucene/Solr provides the relevance level of matching documents based
> on the terms found. To boost a term use the caret symbol ^ with a
> boost factor (a number) at the end of the term you are searching. The
> higher the boost factor, the more relevant the term will be.
>
> Boosting allows you to control the relevance of a document by boosting
> its term. For example, if you are searching for `jakarta apache` and you want the term `jakarta` to be more relevant,
> you can boost it by adding the ^ symbol along with the boost factor
> immediately after the term. For example, you could type:
>
> `jakarta^4 apache`

When using `qf` with `edismax` it applies the same rule to any hits in those fields.

> The `qf` parameter introduces a list of fields, each of which is
> assigned a boost factor to increase or decrease that particular
> field’s importance in the query. For example, the query below:
>
> ```
> qf=fieldOne^2.3 fieldTwo fieldThree^0.4
> ```
>
> assigns `fieldOne` a boost of `2.3`, leaves `fieldTwo` with the default
> boost (because no boost factor is specified), and `fieldThree` a boost
> of `0.4`. These boost factors make matches in `fieldOne` much more
> significant than matches in `fieldTwo`, which in turn are much more
> significant than matches in `fieldThree`.